# Ionic 6 remove scroll bar

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, scrollbar

I tried and search every where but all the tricks that were used to remove the scrollbar in previous versions of ionic are not working with version 6.
Has anyone achieved to do this with current version ?

Comment: From which component html you trying to remove the scrollbar?

Comment: I would remove it from all of them

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good ideia to completely remove the scrollbar for the desktop version of your app. Some people still prefer to use the scrollbar instead of just using the mouse wheel.

But Anyway, on mobile it is hidden automattically so you don't need to(or shouldn't) worry about it. On desktop what I do is custumize the scrollbar so it doesn't look so weird with the rest of the content of the page, but you can also hide it:

On `global.scss`

```
@media only screen and(min-width: 1000px) { // or whatever breakpoint you want to use
  *::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5rem; // set the width to 0 and remove the rest to completely hide the scrollbar
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }

  *::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

Comment: Saddly it has no effect..

Comment: That's weird. I'm currently using Ionic 6 and and this works for me perfectly. Try removing the media query and check if you're modifying the scrollbar someplace else. This could also be a bug.

Comment: It is weird as even the scroll event is not working on any component neither on the ion-app, yes.

Comment: Is it possible that you are using some other librarie that changes the default behavior of the scrollbar?  Try using this on some other project. Also, check if it works on other browsers, could be just a browser compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  overflow-y: hidden; /* Hide vertical scrollbar */
  overflow-x: hidden; /* Hide horizontal scrollbar */
}
```

Comment: has no effect either

Comment: this will completely disable the scrolling